# Run a graph algorithm in an open transaction

Tags: neo4j

I have been testing neo4j for graph projects for 1 or 2 month now and it has been really efficient, but I'm having a hard time finding how to solve one of my problem and I'm seeking for advice.

I'm using neo4j to store graph databases and check that they follow some structural requirements, for example, I have a db modeling dependency between items : the nodes are the items and the links are labeled "need" or "incompatible" to model the dependency and I want neo4j to check the coherence of the data.

I coded the checker in a server plugin and it works very well. But now I would like to allow users to connect to the database, modify the data (without saving the modification yet), check that the modifications are not breaking the coherence and then save the modifications.

I found the http endpoint which can keep a transaction open and it completely fits the "modifying the db without saving" need, but I can't find how to run my checker on the modified data : is there a way to run something else than Cypher query with the http endpoint  or do I have to consider an other way to solve this ?

I now it would be possible to run my checker using the TransactionEventHandler beforeCommit, but it means the user couldn't know if his data are okay without starting a commit, and the fact that the data are split between the db without modification and the TransactionData which store the modification make the checker tricky to apply.

So, if someone knows how I could solve this, it would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options is to use Unmanaged Extension and Transaction Event API.

You are able to handle incoming transaction and read all data which are in it. If transaction break your rules, then you can discard the transaction.

I recommend you to use [GraphAware framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tx-api) for that.

Here is the great article about that http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html

Comment: Thanks, it's easier to manipulate the data this way, but if I get it right, it still can only be done at the commit (just before) of the transaction and not in the middle of it, is there any way to do so without triggering the commit of the transaction ?

Comment: Actually, in the beforeCommit method, you're "in the middle" of the tx. GraphAware Framework gives you the option to "view" two versions of the graph - before and after. So it would partly meet your criteria. But I don't think there is currently a way to do this without attempting to commit a tx.